# Does Web Audio API need a Dedicated Server?

Tags: javascript, server, web-audio-api, latency

I'm currently working on a web application that uses WebAudioAPI to apply filters to audio tracks. Im using my local MAMP server to test things out and everything works great. When I upload my files to my GoDaddy host/server, the audio in my application lags for other machines. I'm trying to find the root of this problem. Is it that GoDaddys server has a latency issue that my local MAMP server doesn't have? or is there a problem with web audio api that i needed to configure somewhere (i.e buffer size of source nodes )

Not sure what to do right now, should I try to get a dedicated server to run my application so there won't be any latency spikes? Or is there something in web audio api that needs to be configured?

If anyone has run into this problem, and has suggestions/solutions that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `local server` vs `server on the internet` - yes, there will be lag/latency issues and no amount of money thrown at it can make any sort of guarantees to remove the latency spikes

Comment: would a dedicated server be better than a regular go daddy server ?

Comment: this is not the place to ask such questions - BUT ... lets say the lag/latency is primarily cause by your gateway to the internet - in that case where you host will make no difference